# How to auto refresh recyclerview content in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hy, i am making an chat application in which i want to auto refresh my current activity like ajax in web. Please post your answer with sample code. Thank you.
I am using APIs for getting and sending messages through JSON and Android Volley.

Comment: please show what you have attempted

Comment: @tyczj I made a function named init() which collects all the data and show that data in recyclerview, additionally i placed a button which calls that function when the button is pressed

Answer (score 3):

You have to notify the adapter when there is any change in the data.
Set your adapter to recycler view and whenever data is changed call setData method and pass updated list.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomHolder>              
  {
    private ArrayList<String> data =  new ArrayList<>();

    public SubjectsAdapter() {}

    public void setData(List<String> newData) {
        this.data.clear();
        data.addAll(newData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        return new CustomHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SubjectsHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textview.setText(data.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is quite good and it helped me alot, but sir i want to know that how can i periodically check that if i get new data in my database of not?

Comment: It depends that how you are taking data from the server...please elaborate your situation.

Comment: i am fetching data through Android Volley from my XAMPP server.

Comment: Then you have to call the server again and again after certain period of time.

Comment: yes i know but i dont know the code to call server again and again, i was asking for that...

Comment: use broadcast reciever  or firebase messaging system

Answer (score 0):

use `notifyDataSetChanged();` after dynamically add new item in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive post delayed handler to update data after a fixed period of time and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter if you have an update